# When blitzcrank uses his rocket grab wile a champion recalls/teleports what happens?

Tags: league-of-legends

if a champion is teleporting or recalling what happens to blitz rocket grab? Does the grab negate the teleport/recall, or would the champion still teleport/recall? I guess this could be asked about Shen's ult and twisted fate as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tf ulting away when he still had a global ult. lol good stuff.

Comment: anytime :D its a hilarious video for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If blitz lands a hook on someone that is recalling, and if it is timed correctly it will pull them all the way back to the location. There is no time frame in either Twisted Fates and Shen's ultimate that this can happen. It will only interrupt the casting animation.

Comment: lol that would be cool to see and thanks for the info....if anyone sees this comment try and post if you have one a video of blitz doing this recall pull thank you :)